# Equivalent method to NavigationService.Refresh in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to refresh the content of my app apge in WP 8.1.  In WP 8, there was:

```
NavigationService.Refresh()
```

But I haven't been able to find anything similar in 8.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw in  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) there is a `Frame.Refresh()` method in wp8.1. You should start with this.

---

`NavigationService.Refresh()` [does not exist on WindowsPhone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.refresh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Here is a trick from @justinmchase :

Navigate to another page (Refresh.xaml for example)

```
private void OnAllowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  LocationService.AllowLocationServices = true;
  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Refresh.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Come back to your page

```
public partial class Refresh : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Refresh()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var j = this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => App.RootFrame.Navigate(j.Source));
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

This example is for wp8. For wp8.1, you have to use : `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Refresh));`

[source](http://justinmchase.com/2012/12/15/redirecting-navigation-in-windows-phone-8/)